# Save image in Gallery in specific Albums in IPHONE

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, object

I want to save image in gallery in specific folder. 
When i click save i am using this code to save image

```
- (IBAction)saveImageToGallery:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"SaveImageToGallery");
/*
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 THis will hide button and take screen shot then will show buttons again
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

[AddImagesToCanvasView setHidden:YES];
[ShareOnCanvas setHidden:YES];
[CanvasButtonForRatio setHidden:YES];

for(UIButton *b in self.view.subviews) {
    if([b isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        b.hidden = YES;
    }
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

for(UIButton *b in self.view.subviews) {
    if([b isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        b.hidden = NO;
    }
}
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

}

i want that when i click save than it open photos so i can create new album or click on existing album and save that image in that album.
How will i do that.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the foolowing code to save the image to specific Album.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Midhun" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Noooo error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
```

Here image is your `UIImage`.

Make sure to include AssetsLibrary framework and `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>`

Please refer this [**tutorial**](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/).

Comment: the app crashed.. i dont know y. and it giving me warning on withCompletionBlock the id is not found

Comment: @Zohaib: please check this tutorial, and check the code in that site. http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/

Answer (score 0):

use this line with path

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

use this bellow code if file type is JPEG

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: what will be in path. i mean how that path will look like?

Comment: like this NSString  *path = [NSHomeDirectory();
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];

Comment: At least read the question once brother. Asker is asking for Album of Native Photo library. In that  case what will the path as per you ?

Comment: I already write that thing in answer at first line.. "use this line with path", it means you can set any path for save image.